# dlsym and parameter checking

Tags: c, plugins, arguments, dlsym

I'm writing a plug-in application in C and I'm using dlopen/dlsym to load dynamically the "implementation" of some functions. For example I have the following pointer to a function

```
struct cti_t* (*create)() = 0;
```

And I load the implementation using the following code:

```
plugin_handle = dlopen ("xxx.so", RTLD_NOW);
//error checking

create = dlsym(plugin_handle, "cti_create");
//error checking

//call create for the specific implenetation
struct cti_t *dev = create();
```

The "plug-in" defines the cti_create in the following way

```
struct cti_t* cti_create(int i) {
   printf("Creating device lcl");
       //do somenthing with i
   return &lcl_cti;
}
```

So it defines one integer parameter, but everything works without errors. The question is: is it possible to make some argument type verification when the symbol is loaded with dlsym? How can I enforce that the symbols loaded have the signature I expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make any argument type verification when loading with dlsym if the function is a C function -- there's nothing in the image to define the arguments (or the return type). If you were working with C++ (and did not declare the symbol to have `extern "C"` linkage), then the type checking would be embedded in the actual symbol name. That being said, at the time of calling `dlsym()` you would have to pass in the mangled C++ name, not "cti_create".